# Open specific tab from main menu while app is running in foreground using pending intent or other solution

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

In my app, there is a login activity first and a home activity. After logging in using volley and passing parameters to home activity in an intent, I'm able to start a foreground service that keeps the app running in background with notifications and getting back to home activity by clicking on the notification with the help of pending intent.

Now, I'm searching for how to open the app from main menu and accessing directly home activity with the pending intent of the foreground service. Maybe should I pass the parameters of the pending intent to the login activity and check them to redirect to home activity, but i'am stuck with this and don't understand.

Here is the login activity Page :

```
    EditText username, password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signIn);
        // Login On Button Click
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            login();}
        });
// THIS IS THE SOLUTION THAT I THOUGHT ABOUT : if the intent is not null open HomeActivity
        Intent startinIntent = getIntent();
        if (startinIntent.getStringExtra("userLogged") != null && !startinIntent.getStringExtra("userLogged").isEmpty()) {
           String userLogged = startinIntent.getStringExtra("userLogged");
           Intent startAgain = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
           tackBackWork.putExtra("userLogged", userLogged);
           startActivity(startAgain);
            Log.d("this is the ilue", userLogged);
        }
    }
    private void login(){
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {
                //input your API parameters
                object.put("u",username.getText());
                object.put("p",password.getText());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Enter the correct url for your api service site
            String url = getResources().getString(R.string.loginUrl);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try{
                                String msg = response.getString("msg");
                                if(msg.contains("true")){
                                    Intent loggedIn = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                    loggedIn.putExtra("userLogged", response.toString());
                                    startActivity(loggedIn);
                                    finish();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identifiants Incorrectes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "erreur - 200 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley on error listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
}
```

Here is the Home activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        String userLogged = getIntent().getStringExtra("userLogged");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServiceNoPopup.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServiceNoPopup.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userLogged = intent.getStringExtra("userLogged");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("userLogged", userLogged);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userLogged = intent.getStringExtra("userLogged");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("userLogged", userLogged);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userLogged = intent.getStringExtra("userLogged");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("userLogged", userLogged);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is foreground Service Page :

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        String userLogged = intent.getStringExtra("userLogged");
        Intent backToHomeActivity = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        backToHomeActivity.putExtra("userLogged", userLogged);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, backToHomeActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Example Service")
               // .setLargeIcon()
               // .setColor()
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm new to all of this. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use SharedPreferences.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button login;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(sp.getBoolean("logged",false)){
            goToMainActivity();
        }

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToMainActivity();
                sp.edit().putBoolean("logged",true).apply();
            }
        });
    }

    public void goToMainActivity(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

See the Tutorial below 
https://medium.com/@prakharsrivastava_219/keep-the-user-logged-in-android-app-5fb6ce29ed65